# Display function output in label widget

Tags: python, tkinter

how to display `angular_velocity_sol` (from angular velocity function) in a tkinter label.
The angular_velocity function is in (functions.py) file, and label is in (gear_tcl.py) file, both files are in the same folder.

angular_velocity function in (functions.py) file:

```
from gui import *

def angular_velocity(var, indx, mode):
    N = angular_velocity_arg.get()
    angular_velocity_sol = (omega_eq.subs([(N_RPM, N), (pi, round(math.pi, 2))])).rhs
    # print(angular_velocity_sol)
    return angular_velocity_sol
```

tkinter entry and label widgets in (gear_tcl.py) file:

```
from tkinter import *
from functions import *

...

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        
        ...        

        angular_velocity_arg = DoubleVar()

        self.omegaEntry = tk.Entry(self.omegaEntryFrame, textvariable=angular_velocity_arg)
        angular_velocity_arg.trace_add("write", angular_velocity)

        self.omegaEntryAnswer = tk.Label(self.omegaEntryFrame)
        self.omegaEntryAnswer.configure(text='function output must be here.')
```

the code works fine when I put `angular_velocity` function at the same file as tkinter (gui_tcl.py), but as soon as I move the function into a different file the code is not working anymore.

Comment: Even putting `angular_velocity()` in the same file, it still does not work because `angular_velocity_arg` is a local variable inside `__init__()` and it is not accessible inside `angular_velocity()` except `angular_velocity()` is a nested function inside `__init__()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for the responde. Yes the function works well inside `__init__`, But i want to put it in different file and display the result in `self.omegaEntryAnswer` label, any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `angular_velocity_arg` is a local variable inside `__init__()`, it cannot be accessed outside the function.

I would suggest:

- change `angular_velocity_arg` to instance variable `self.angular_velocity_arg`
- define new class method for `.trace()`
- pass the input value to `angular_velocity()` inside the newly defined function and get the returned result, then show the result in the label

Updated `angular_velocity()`:

```py
def angular_velocity(N):
    angular_velocity_sol = (omega_eq.subs([(N_RPM, N), (pi, round(math.pi, 2))])).rhs
    # print(angular_velocity_sol)
    return angular_velocity_sol
```

Updated `Toplevel1` class:

```py
class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        ...

        # changed to instance variable
        self.angular_velocity_arg = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.omegaEntry = tk.Entry(self.omegaEntryFrame, textvariable=self.angular_velocity_arg)
        # changed trace callback
        self.angular_velocity_arg.trace_add("write", self.on_trace)

        self.omegaEntryAnswer = tk.Label(self.omegaEntryFrame)
        ...

    def on_trace(self, *args):
        try:
            # get the input value and pass it to angular_velocity()
            result = angular_velocity(self.angular_velocity_arg.get())
            # show the returned result in the label
            self.omegaEntryAnswer["text"] = f"Result = {result}"
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```

Comment: When I run the code I get `AttributeError: 'Toplevel1' object has no attribute 'on_trace'`, so I updated the code to be `self.angular_velocity_arg.trace_add("write", on_trace)`, now when I run the code and enter a value I get the following message: `'str' object has no attribute 'angular_velocity_arg'`

Comment: I think you have defined `on_trace()` outside `Toplevel1` class.  Study carefully what I wrote.

Comment: One last question, if I have more functions that work exactly as `angular_velocity()`, and more entry and label widgets for each function,                                                 is it a good idea to make `on_trace()` change all their label?

Comment: I would suggest not using trace.  One of the way is to use a button to trigger a function that do what you want.  It really depends on how your application is designed.

Comment: I wanted the program to display the output instantly while entering data, so the user can see the output (calculation result) before processing to next step. But, if using trace is not good, I can search for alternatives.